# SQL Data Formatting

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 15 files that I upload to a SQL Server database each month and recently the entity I receive the files from added leading zeros and a +/- sign before dollar amounts. Is there a way I can clean this data up prior to it coming into the database? The format is this: +00000000539.85 or -00000000294.99

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Will it work if you use data type `money`?

Comment: You can use the derived column transformation to generate a column that doesn't have the plus/minus or leading zeroes, if that's what you mean.